# Second noty message has no modal background

Tags: jquery, background, noty

I'm using this :

```
function action(type, layout, text) {
    var n = noty({
        type: type,
        layout: layout,
        text: text,
        dismissQueue: true,
        theme: 'relax',
        modal: true,
        maxVisible: 1,
        timeout: false,
    });
}

action('information', 'center', 'one two');
$.noty.closeAll();
action('information', 'center', 'three four');
```

Which can be seen running here:
**http://jsfiddle.net/1nr4f7L5/1/**

When the first action notification is shown the screens background is darkened.

Yet as soon as the second noficiation is shown the background goes back to it's default white.

Why ? Can I have it so the background stays grey all the time ? until noty has finished ?

Thanks

Comment: The issue appears to be because the animation hiding the modal background hasn't completed when you open the next modal: http://jsfiddle.net/1nr4f7L5/2/ This is a solution, but I'm not going to post it as an answer as there should be callbacks you can use.

Comment: Thanks - I can see how that works.. is there any way to do this without having the background go white then dark again ?

Answer (score 0):

That works for me.

```
function createNoty()
{
    var n = noty({
        text: 'hi',
        layout: 'center',
        modal: true,
        type: 'information',
        template: template,        
        animation: {
            open: { height: 'toggle' },
            close: { height: 'toggle' },
            easing: 'swing',
            speed: 0 // opening & closing animation speed
        },
        closeWith: ['button']
    });
}

n1 = createNoty();
n1.show();
n2 = createNoty();
n1.close();
n2.show();
```